# Dynamically generating data for map tiles from Python function

Tags: python, geoserver, mapserver, mapnik, tilecache

I'm brand-new to GIS and relatively new to web services. I've found a ton of great resources on the web, but I'm having trouble addressing one specific issue:

One of the data layers on my planned map is dynamically generated in Python from some scattered and dynamic data (it is the "results" output of a computational weather-related model). I can generate this layer in chunks of arbitrary size and location, and output in any standard format (a numpy array, a .png, a geotiff (using GDAL), etc.), and I can expose a function such as:

```
def create_tile(width, height, ulc_lat, ulc_lon, lrc_lat, lrc_lon):
```

to hide the implementation details.

But, how do I get this layer to display in the map? The options that I can see right now are:

- Serve as a WMS by creating a new Layer Type in a Python-based WMS server such as TileCache or [TileLite](https://bitbucket.org/springmeyer/tilelite/wiki/Home) ... this is probably what I'll try unless someone has a better idea.
- Implement as a [PythonDataSource](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Python-Plugin) in Mapnik. *Problem:* It's a new feature, requires custom compilation, and causes Mapnik to segfault even on the provided examples.
- Somehow map filenames on disk (my_tile_z0_x3_y4) so that their contents is generated on-demand by the create_tile function above... I have no idea how this would be done, though.
- Create the layer on disk ahead of time, and re-generate it often to keep the appearance of being "dynamic". (lots of disk space, needless CPU use, etc)

Does anybody have any suggestions? It seems like this must be a common problem, but I can't find any standard solution...

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: try tilestache, its not that hard

Comment: thanks for the tip. I ended up using TileCache just because I needed to serve as WMS, and it went surprisingly smoothly... it was really easy to create a new Layer type.